# For nginx-ingress controller, when setting controller loadblancer whitelist IP ranges (NOT ingress whitelist ranges), is this visible on GCP console?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

We have an nginx ingress controller in the cluster with [whitelist annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range) on the ingress resources. This all works as expected. Traffic comes into the controller and gets 403ed if it does not match the ranges on the ingress. No problem there.

We now have moved this onto the loadbalancer (e.g. to block the traffic at the loadbalancer level, rather than at the ingress resource level), using the `controller.service.loadBalancerSourceRanges`. This creates `.spec.loadBalancerSourceRanges` in the service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    ...
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  clusterIP: x.x.x.x
  clusterIPs:
  - x.x.x.x
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  healthCheckNodePort: 31564
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 10.0.0.0/8
  - 192.168.0.0/16
  - 172.17.0.0/16
  - ...
  - ...
  ports:
  ....
  selector:
    ...
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: x.x.x.x
```

Everything works here as expected too. Any traffic not in the whitelist doesn't successfully connect to the controller pods as the cloud provider's loadbalancer is not passing it through.

My question, however, is this: is there a way we can see these ranges on the loadbalancer within the console (GCP in my case)?

In other words, if I picked a Google LB that was being used by an ingress controller, how would I see what (if any) CIDR ranges have been allowed on that loadbalancer?

Answer (score 0):

GKE does two things when it encounters `spec:loadBalancerSourceRanges` in a service manifest:

1. Configures firewall rules on the GKE nodes
2. Configures a firewall rule for your VPC.

The VPC firewall rule name(s) should start with `k8s`.

Comment: Thanks, I dumped all the firewall rules in json format (`gcloud compute firewall-rules list --format=json`) and searched through the source ranges looking for the ones I had added (for example, the 10.0.0.0/8 range) and could not find that in any of the firewall rules. Am I looking in the right place?